# Scala Generic Class invoke class method

Tags: scala

I am currently learning generic class in Scala. I have created below codes, which it has a class to store a list of items that extends from `ItemInterface`; and it can use `printAllId` as a way to access the `printID` method of each element. However, I am having "value printID is not a member of ItemInterface".

```scala
trait ItemInterface:
    def printID(): Unit 

class Item(id: String) extends ItemInterface:
    def printID(): Unit = println(id) 


class ItemsContainer[ItemInterface]:
    private var objects: List[ItemInterface] = Nil

    def add(item: ItemInterface): Unit = 
        objects = objects :+ item

    def printAllId(): Unit = 
        objects.foreach(item => item.printID())
```

Comment: You should remove the `[ItemInterface]` in `class ItemsContainer[ItemInterface]`

Answer (score 4):

By declaring your class as:

```scala
class ItemsContainer[ItemInterface]:
```

You've declared the class to be generic with a type parameter called `ItemInterface` which is then hiding the trait with the same name.

Said differently, your code is the same as:

```scala
class ItemsContainer[A]:
    private var objects: List[A] = Nil

    def add(item: A): Unit = 
        objects = objects :+ item

    def printAllId(): Unit = 
        objects.foreach(item => item.printID())
```

Removing the type parameter in the declaration is enough to solve this:

```scala
class ItemsContainer:
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to be able to restrict your `ItemsContainer` to a specific subtype of `ItemInterface`, you could declare it as `class ItemsContainer[A <: ItemInterface]` (with `A` as type for `private var objects: List[A]` and `def add(item: A): Unit`).